# How do I show all the files in a directory with a name containing a number?

Tags: linux, ls

How do I show all the files in a directory with a name contain a number? I tried

```
ls [0-9] textfiles
```

(`textfiles`) is my directory.

This is how my Linux pocket guide shows me. I am just trying to display all the files that contain a number in the name. I have actually tried about 20+ variations that I found in my book and online.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want something like

```
ls textfiles/*[0-9]*
```

or (if "`textfiles` is my directory" means you're inside the directory):

```
ls *[0-9]*
```

Note these commands don't restrict themselves to regular files. Directories, symlinks, named pipes and other entries may match. In broad Unix context all these are "files" and such matching is done with respect to their names only. To tell regular files apart, you need another tool like `find`.

I'm surprised any guide advised you `ls [0-9] textfiles` as it makes little sense in the context of your question.

To decode `*[0-9]*` refer to `man 7 glob` or e.g. [this article](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm), *Standard Wildcards (globbing patterns)* section. It's worth noticing in the above cases it's the shell (not `ls`!) that expands the given pattern.

Comment: @StPatrick Please take our quick [tour] to learn what you can do with an answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

`find` also works, and can display only files, for example in the current dir (`.`):

```
find . -type f -name "*[0-9]*"
```

It's recursive by default, but use `-maxdepth 1` to avoid that.